# How to load unsigned ints into SIMD

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd, unsigned-integer

I have a C program where I have a few arrays of unsigned ints. I'm using this declaration `uint32_t`.

I want to use SIMD to perform some operations on the data stored in each of the arrays. This is where I'm stuck because it looks like most of the SSE and SSE2 functions only support float and double.

What's the best way for me to load data of type `uint32_t`?

Comment: `MOVDQA/MOVDQU` are SSE2. So are `PADD[B/W/D/Q]`, and *many* other vector-instructions. Why do you think SSE2 is only for `float/double`?

Answer (score 1):

For any integer SSE type, regardless of element width or signedness, you typically use `_mm_load_si128`/`_mm_loadu_si128`:

```
uint32_t a[N];

__m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)a);
```